# How to return a value from Firebase to a react component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I am trying to read a value from RealtimeDatabase on Firebase and render it in an element, but it keeps returning undefined. I have the following code:

```
const getStudentName = (studentId) => {
    firebase.database().ref('students').child(studentId).on("value", (snapshot) => {
        return snapshot.val().name; 
    })
}

const StudentName = (studentId) => ( <p>{getStudentName(studentId)}</p> )
```

I know it's nothing wrong with the database itself or the value I'm finding, because if I do:

```
const getStudentName = (studentId) => {
    firebase.database().ref('students').child(studentId).on("value", (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val().name);
        return "Test"; 
    })
}
```

I still see a correct name from my database outputted to console as expected, yet "Test" is not returned to the element. However, if I do it like this:

```
const getStudentName = (studentId) => {
    firebase.database().ref('students').child(studentId).on("value", (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val().name);
    })
    return "Test"; 
}
```

then "Test" is returned to the

element and displayed. I'm very confused, as I don't understand how my console.log() can be reached inside the function but a 'return' statement right after it will not return.

New to React and Firebase, please help! Thank you.

EDIT: I'm sure it's self-explanatory, but you can assume a simple database in the form:

```
{ "students": [
    "0": { "name": "David" },
    "1": { "name": "Sally" } ]}
```

If 'studentId' is 0 then 'console.log(snapshot.val().name)' successfully outputs 'David', but 'David' will not return to the

element.

Comment: Your Firebase call is *asynchronous*. You can't return directly from it like you are expecting. However, there are a number of ways to deal with that situation. [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't *return* something from an asynchronous call like that. If you check in the debugger or add some logging, you'll see that your outer `return "Test"` runs before the `console.log(snapshot.val().name)` is ever called.

Instead in React you'll want to use a `useState` hook (or `setState` method) to tell React about the new value, so that it can then rerender the UI.

I recommend reading the React documentation on the [using the state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), and the documentation on [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: Thank you! I've been experimenting the last few days and building my app successfully using this sort of mentality. This exposed a lot of other problems, but in resolving them I've developed a much stronger grasp of React. Thanks again!

Comment: Good to hear @Chris 

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you are consuming `getStudentName`, but your current code makes attaches a real-time listener to that database location. Each time the data at that location updates, your callback function gets invoked. Because of that, returning a value from such a function doesn't make much sense.

If you instead meant to fetch the name from the database just once, you can use the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#once) method, which returns a `Promise` containing the value you are looking for.

As another small optimization, if you only need the student's name, consider fetching `/students/{studentId}/name` instead.

```
const getStudentName = (studentId) => {
    return firebase.database()
      .ref("students")
      .child(studentId)
      .child("name")
      .once("value")
      .then(nameSnapshot => nameSnapshot.val());
}
```

With the above code, `getStudentName(studentId)` now returns a `Promise<string | null>`, where `null` would be returned when that student doesn't exist.

```
getStudentName(studentId)
  .then(studentName => { /* ... do something ... */ })
  .catch(err => { /* ... handle errors ... */ })
```

If instead you were filling a `<Student>` component, continuing to use the `on` snapshot listener may be the better choice:

```
const Student = (props) => {
  const [studentInfo, setStudentInfo] = useState({ status: "loading", data: null, error: null });

  useEffect(() => {
    // build reference
    const studentDataRef = firebase.database()
      .ref("students")
      .child(props.studentId)
      .child("name");

    // attach listener
    const listener = studentDataRef.on(
      'value',
      (snapshot) => {
        setStudentInfo({
          status: "ready",
          data: snapshot.val(),
          error: null
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        setStudentInfo({
          status: "error",
          data: null,
          error
        });
      }
    );

    // detach listener in unsubscribe callback
    return () => studentDataRef.off(listener);
  }, [props.studentId]); // <- run above code whenever props.studentId changes

  // handle the different states while the data is loading
  switch (studentInfo.status) {
    case "loading":
      return null; // hides component, could also show a placeholder/spinner
    case "error":
      return (
        <div class="error">
          Failed to retrieve data: {studentInfo.error.message}
        </div>
      );
  }

  // render data using studentInfo.data
  return (
    <div id={"student-" + props.studentId}>
      <img src={studentInfo.data.image} />
      <span>{studentInfo.data.name}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Because of how often you might end up using that above `useState`/`useEffect` combo, you could rewrite it into your own `useDatabaseData` hook.